# How can I fix the thumbnails display problem on TYPO3

Tags: imagemagick, typo3, thumbnails, typo3-10.x

I'm having a problem with the TYPO3 version 10.4.11.
Thumbnails do not display in filelist for jpg and png files. (see screenshots). Work with svg file.
[image: printscreen11]

[image: settings image test]

Comment: please separate your 3(?) questions into separate questions on SO

Comment: As environment settings showing error, install ImageMagick on your server,

Comment: do the imagetests in the installtool/ Environment Module.

Comment: Settings seems good now, but how resolve this problem? Thumbnails are still not displayed.

Comment: @Okd_ch To get the thumbnails back you have to remove the temporary assets from Admin Tools -> Maintenance

Answer (score 0):

Install ImageMagick on your server. Sure a problem with ImageMagick, svg images are not converted so they are displayed correctly.